The app build failed to produce artifact folder: '.next'. Please ensure this property is configured correctly in your deployment configuration file
I have a nextJs application and i am trying to deploy it on azure static websites, and i am getting the below error:

The app build failed to produce artifact folder: '.next'. Please ensure this property is configured correctly in your deployment configuration file.

Below is my yaml file
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '20.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: node --version
  displayName: 'Verify Node.js version'

- script: |
    cd code
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'Build Next.js application'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: 'code/.next'  
    artifactName: 'next-js-artifact'


- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
  inputs:
    azure_static_web_apps_api_token: 'My_Token_value_here'
    app_location: '/' 
    artifact_location: 'next-js-artifact'
    output_location: '.next' 


I did a changeDirectory command as my code repo has a folder "code" therefore i did "cd code "
and below is my code of package.json
 "scripts": {
    "path":"cd code",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "build:azure" :"next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "storybook": "storybook dev -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "storybook build"
  },


First， the artifact_location is not contained in the Inputs of AzureStaticWebApp@0 task. So, you can't use it like this. The publishBuildArtifacts@1 is not needed.
I use the code sample Next.js Starter (Static Sites) and I also put the code in a folder "code" to test the issue.
Compared with your code, there is a difference in the build command from package.json. It adds the export command after the build command, which becomes "build": "next build && next export". Then we can find where the files are exported from the log of the build task.

Then we can use the AzureStaticWebApp@0 as the following yaml:
  steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '20.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: node --version
    displayName: 'Verify Node.js version'


  - script: |
      cd code
      npm install
      npm run build
    displayName: 'Build Next.js application'
    
  - script: ls -R
    displayName: 'list files to check the out put file path'

  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: "my token"
      app_location: '/code'    #The directory location of the application source code, relative to the working directory. The default Working directory is  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory).
      output_location: 'out'    #The directory location of the compiled application code after building is complete, relative to the working directory.


You can also check more details from the official document : Deploy static-rendered Next.js websites on Azure Static Web Apps.

Hi @Miao I am getting below error now
The app build failed to produce artifact folder: 'code/index.html'. Please ensure this property is configured correctly in your deployment configuration file.

Hi @CodeNoob, what is the value of your output_location? The app_location is the  directory location of the application source code. The output_location is The directory location of the compiled application code after building is complete. In my test, they should be '/code' and 'out'.

Hi, from the new error, did you change the output_location to  'code/index.html'? Can you try the app_location: '/code' and output_location: 'out' ?
